# jqGrid zebra striping

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, zebra-striping

Does jqGrid support zebra striping?  I can't see any examples.

By zebra striping I mean each even row has one color and each odd row has another color.

Currently we are using JQuery UI themes to theme our grids..  ideally the way we do striping won't interfere with us using the UI themes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use the [altRows and altclass options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions).

Comment: Is there a way you can use this with your JQuery UI theme?

Comment: Using `altRows:true` is there a CSS class included in the JQuery UI themes that will be used by jqGrid?  Or will the CSS class be a specific class used by jqGrid?  I see you can provide your own class using `altclass` but I'd prefer to let the JQuery UI theme designers design the class..

Comment: @Marcus: deafult value of the `altclass` is `'ui-priority-secondary'`. It is full JQuery UI themes conform, but in my opinion one can see very difficult the results of the class `'ui-priority-secondary'` in the themes redmond which I mostly use.