# how to set the cell background color baced on the cell value in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid. I need to set background color of the cell based on the values.

I have tried  using the following code after reload the table the color is disabled.

> jQuery("#list").setCell
>   ('5','5','t',{background:'#ff0000'});

I want to set the cell background color on table loading, based on the cell values.
how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this in many ways: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942761/how-to-change-the-color-of-jqgrid-cell/4943722#4943722), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369899/jqgrid-zebra-alt-rows-background-not-working-due-to-ui-theme-class/4382122#4382122) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244909/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-cell-in-a-jqgrid-custom-formatter/4981389#4981389). Important is not only how you do this, but **where**. The `loadComplete` event handle is the good place for that.

**UPDATED**: In the next version of jqGrid you will able to use new `cellattr` option as function in the `colModel`. See [this demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UnobtrusiveLinksNew.htm) and [my original suggestion](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/custom-cell-tooltips-used-title-property-of-colmodel-as-the-function/).

Answer (score 1):

To use the `cellattr` functionality with the asp.net library of jqGrid, add this to your column.  I can't find this documented well anywhere else online...

```
<Formatter>
    <trirand:CustomFormatter SetAttributesFunction="clientSideFunctionName" />
</Formatter>
```

And Thank Oleg for the awesome addition to jqGrid :)