# jqgrid alternate row background

Tags: colors, jqgrid, background, mouseover

Currently I am able to apply custom background color for odd number rows. My code to do is

```
$("tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background", "#FCF9E6");
```

on loadComplete, i am executing this code. By default on mouse over and on select of a row, I am getting background color as yellow only for even numbered rows not for odd numbered rows. How to apply custom background color along with mouse over & row selection background color functionality?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you will find the answer on your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369899/jqgrid-zebra-alt-rows-background-not-working-due-to-ui-theme-class/4382122#4382122) with the corresponding [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/altclassTests.htm).